# MSVC 19.22 emitts C4626 Warning on Lambda

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, c++20

Warning C4626 is preventing us from moving from std:c++17 to std:c++latest. It gets emitted since 19.22 (not in 19.21 or earlier) on mostly every lambda.

```
#pragma warning(default : 4626)

int main()
{
    int foo;
    auto bar = [&]() {
        foo;
    };

  return 0;
}


<source>(8): warning C4626: 'main::<lambda_1>': assignment operator was implicitly defined as deleted
```

Compiled with  /std:c++latest /W4

This warning is not wrong at all, but way to verbose in my opinion. We would like to keep C4626 enabled to get a warning when deriving from an exlicitly/implcitly deleted assignment operator. Because we map every warning as an error this is not possible right now.

Is this level of verbosity wanted? Or can it be described as a bug?

Comment: Seems like a regression to me. The [C4626 documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-warnings/compiler-warning-level-4-c4626?view=vs-2019) explicitly talks about base and derived classes, which should have no relation to lambdas. Maybe MSVC now has every lambda derive from some base as an implementation detail (no idea why that would be useful), but from a C++ standard perspective no inheritance happens in this code.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known bug that has been reported to the MSVC developer team; the [current status](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/749985/msvc-1922-emitts-c4626-warning-on-simple-lambdas-w.html) is "fixed pending release" (in Version 16.5).

In the meantime, the problem can be worked around using the `#pragma warning(suppress:4626)` directive, [which disables the warning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/warning?view=vs-2019) but only for the **very next** line of code:

> *suppress* - Pushes the current state of the pragma on the stack, disables
>   the specified warning for the next line, and then pops the warning
>   stack so that the pragma state is reset.

Alternatively, using the MSVC `__pragma()` syntax, one can conditionally define an `ENDLAMBDA` (or whatever you want to call it) macro, as follows (you would only need this once, in your top-level, ".pch-forming" header):

```cpp
#if (__cplusplus > 201703L) // Using the "/std:c++latest" option...
#define ENDLAMBDA __pragma(warning(suppress:4626))
#else                       // Don't need it for earlier standards:
#define ENDLAMBDA
#endif
```

Then, in any lambda expression, just add this macro before the closing `}`; so, in your example, you could have this:

```cpp
int main()
{
    int foo;
    auto bar = [&]() {
        foo;
    ENDLAMBDA };
    return 0;
}
```

A bit clumsy, I admit - but it will work as a temporary stop-gap until 16.5 is released and, then, it will be fairly easy to search and remove all occurrences of the macro.

Comment: Thanks for the kind reply, and the recommandations. Actually the bug was reported by myself and iam looking forward for 16.5. In the meantime we disabled the warning like you suggested.